# Are there any rings where $0$ has a multiplicative inverse?

Tags: ring-theory, definition, inverse

I am trying to wrap my head around rings (defined to have unity). I get that in a nontrivial ring, $0$ by definition does not have a multiplicative inverse (so is not a unit). But in the trivial ring $\{0\}$ the multiplicative identity is $0$, so in that case I would say that $0$ does have a multiplicative inverse. And so in this case it actually does make sense to write something like $0 = 0^{-1}= -0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523391/why-must-be-the-additive-and-multiplicative-identities-in-a-field-be-different/2523411#2523411

Comment: Correct. In the trivial ring with only one element, $0=1$ and therefore $0$ has a multiplicative inverse. Some authors disallow this ring for this reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since $0 = 1$ in the trivial ring we have $0.0 = 0 = 1$ hence $0$ is a unit and is its own inverse.

Also notice that every ring where $0 = 1$ must be trivial since for any element $r$ in such a ring $r = r.1 = r.0 = 0$

And as suggested by a user in the comments, if $0$ has an inverse in a ring, then this ring is trivial too. Call the inverse $x$. Then $0 = 0.x = 1$ hence by what I wrote earlier the ring is trivial.

Comment: Also notice that if $0$ has an inverse, then $1=0$ beacuse $0\cdot 0^{-1}=1$ (due to being multiplicative inverse) and $0\cdot 0^{-1}=0$ (because $0\cdot x=0$ for all $x$).

Comment: Correct. I will edit that into the answer.