# Making definitions so that $\{0\}$ is not a field.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, definition

I have a follow-up question to my question here: [Are there any rings where $0$ has a multiplicative inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539634/are-there-any-rings-where-0-has-a-multiplicative-inverse)

Here it was made clear that in the trivial ring $\{0\}$ the element $0$ does have a multiplicative inverse. From some of the linked answers and comment([Are there any rings where $0$ has a multiplicative inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539634/are-there-any-rings-where-0-has-a-multiplicative-inverse#comment5243798_2539634)) it was pointed out that this is one of the reasons that some people don't allow rings with $1=0$ (I think).

I can see that if one defines a field as a commutative ring where all non-zero elements have multiplicative inverses, then $\{0\}$ is a field.

My question is if the following is correct way to avoid having $\{0\}$ be a field by simply defining a field as a commutative ring with $R^\times = R\setminus \{0\}$. (Here $R^\times$ is the set of units). If this is the definition of a field, then for the trivial (commutative) ring $\{0\}$ we would have
$$
R^\times = \{0\} \neq R\setminus \{0\}.
$$

Did I do that right?

Comment: Just make $0 \neq 1$ part of the definition of a field.

Comment: @Randall: But is my definition correct?

Comment: A field can be defined as a ring $R$ such that $R-\{0\}$ equipped with multiplication is an abelian group (hence contains an identity element).

Comment: @JohnDoe  yes, by defining a field to be a commutative ring $R$ with identity so that $R-\{0\}$ gives a group under multiplication, you are requiring (implicitly) that $1 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Randall: I guess my approach is to define a field as commutative ring with $R^\times = R\setminus \{0\}$. It is a theorem that $R^{\times}$ is a group.

Comment: Yeah, same diff.

Comment: So you want "The set of units is $R\setminus\{0\}$" as part of the definition? I think that would work.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes! I would define a field a being a commutative ring with $R^\times$ (the set/group of units) equal to $R\setminus \{0\}$. Would you write an answer?

Comment: "By a field we will mean every infinite system of real or complex numbers so closed in itself and perfect that addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division of any two of these numbers again yields a number of the system.
— Richard Dedekind, 1871"

Clearly $\{0\}$ is not infinite, so it works for the question...

Answer (score 5):

To my mind, the cleanest definition is:

> **Definition:** A field is a commutative ring with exactly two quotients (namely, the field itself and $0$), or equivalently with exactly two ideals.

Said another way, fields are the [simple objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object) in commutative rings. The zero ring $\{ 0 \}$ is still a ring (and you really want it in your theory, because it's the [terminal object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) in the category of rings), it's just not a field by this definition because it has only one quotient / only one ideal.

The nLab calls this general phenomenon [too simple to be simple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple). Here are some other definitions along these lines:

- A simple group is a group with exactly two quotient groups, or equivalently exactly two normal subgroups. The trivial group $\{ 1 \}$ is not simple.
- A connected graph is a graph with exactly one connected component (where a connected component of a graph is an equivalence class under the equivalence relation generated by being connected by an edge). The empty graph is not connected.
- A prime is a positive integer with exactly two divisors. $1$ is not a prime.

(The reason for the flip between one and two is that some of these definitions describe "connected components" directly and some of these definitions describe, in some sense, the lattice of subsets of connected components.)

There are also some interesting things known about which definitions of a field are and aren't equivalent [constructively](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/field#constructive); for example, some of the obvious definitions don't apply constructively to $\mathbb{R}$!

Answer (score 3):

There are more handy definitions based on $R-\{0\}$ where $R$ is a ring with identity:

- trivial ring if $R-\{0\}=\varnothing$.
- ring without zero-divisors if $R-\{0\}$  is a monoid.
- integral domain if $R-\{0\}$  is a commutative monoid.
- division ring if $R-\{0\}$ is a group.
- field if $R-\{0\}$  is a commutative group.

Answer (score 2):

One of the field axioms is called the non triviality axiom and asks that $1 \neq 0$

For your question, this would certainly work but it is much easier to just ask that $0 \neq 1$, but in the end, it doesn't matter which definition we use, as long as they are equivalent (which is the case here)